# Converting given ambiguous arithmetic expression grammar to unambiguous LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

In this term, I have course on Compilers and we are currently studying syntax - different grammars and types of parsers. I came across a problem which I can't exactly figure out, or at least I can't make sure I'm doing it correctly. I already did 2 attempts and counterexamples were found.
I am given this ambiguous grammar for arithmetic expressions:
E → E+E | E-E | E*E | E/E | E^E | -E | (E)| id | num , where ^ stands for power.

I figured out what the priorities should be. Highest priority are parenthesis, followed by power, followed by unary minus, followed by multiplication and division, and then there is addition and substraction. I am asked to convert this into **equivalent LL(1) grammar**. So I wrote this:

- E → E+A | E-A | A
- A → A*B | A/B | B
- B → -C | C
- C → D^C | D
- D → (E) | id | num

What seems to be the problem with this is not **equivalent grammar** to the first one, although it's non-ambiguous. For example: Given grammar can recognize input: **--5** while my grammar can't. How can I make sure I'm covering all cases? How should I modify my grammar to be equivalent with the given one? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, I would of course do elimination of left recursion and left factoring to make this LL(1), but first I need to figure out this main part I asked above.

Comment: Can you recheck what you wrote? I am trying to follow the logic but there is no C on the right side anywhere except right from C itself. I guess you wanted to write something else

Comment: updated: http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?1021470

Comment: Thank you! I will try testing this grammar on some corner cases but it looks okay at first sight, also I can notice the fix around that minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that should work for your case

```
E = E+A | E-A | A
A = A*C | A/C | C
C = C^B | B
B = -B | D
D = (E) | id | num
```

As a sidenote: pay also attention to the requirements of your task since [some applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Exceptions) might assign higher priority to the unary minus operator with respect to the power binary operator.

Comment: I will test it as I said in comments. Thanks! By the way, why would you do that considering priorities? I have seen that in most languages power has higher priority, exception are programs like Excel and one another, I can't remember at the moment. But considering programming languages that support power as operator, most, as I have read, consider power having higher priority

Comment: @LukaBulatovic I suppose it really boils down to your specific problem, I'm editing the post with a small [memorandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorandum)

Comment: What would be your modification to swap these priorities?